# Google Add-on for sheets invalid scope

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/cats-quickstart)  I am attempting to extend by adding the add-on via the sidebar. [See the screen shot below] [[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nffEc.png)

But I am getting this error when attempting to add this auth scope.

```
Error: invalid_scope

Some requested scopes were invalid. {valid= 
[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.addons.metadata.readonly, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute], invalid= 
[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.addons.execute]}
```

My question is do I need this `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.addons.execute` for sheets to see the homepage triggers in my manifest? If not what am I overlooking?

Comment: Great find, I was pulling my hair out over this for the past few hours!  It works perfectly in my personal account which also has the updated editor but my business account has the old editor and it wasn't working so I thought I had done something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**
We now have support for Workspace Add-ons in Google Sheets, Google Docs and Google Slides (though it may not be available in all regions as yet)...Google Forms is not yet supported.

---

What you want to do is not possible as you can only create **Editor Add-ons** for Google Sheets not **GSuite Add-ons**.

There are distinct differences between the two.

---

**GSuite Add-ons** are currently only applicable to:

1. Gmail
2. Google Drive
3. Google Calendar

---

**Editor Add-ons** are currently only applicable to:

1. Google Sheets
2. Google Forms
3. Google Docs
4. Google Slides

---

See [add-on types documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/types) for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're experiencing this issue because the feature hasn't rolled out yet to your account.

It appears this is a Google Workspace account so you need to navigate to https://admin.google.com/ac/accountsettings/preferences

And select "New Feature"

Then you must select "Rapid Release" and the new Google Workspace add-on feature will be enabled for you probably within 15 minutes but it can take up to 24 hours.

I was experiencing this same issue and once I added this it worked fine.

Also, there isn't an auth scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.addons.execute`

You need to simply add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

and it will work perfectly.  Good luck!